# Is it possible to run a same jenkins build job in parallel stages in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkin job name called **A**. I want this to run in parallel on different nodes in jenkins pipeline. When i try to run this, my job is in queue even when i try to run in different node.

sample code is below. I have added exact syntax of build job inside steps. For demonstration purpose i have added comments only. Thanks for help in advance

```
pipeline{
 agent none
   stages{
     stage("A"){
       parallel{
         stage("A1"){
            agent{
               label 'node a'
            }
            steps{
              // build job with name A
           }

         }
         stage("A2"){
            agent{
               label 'node b'
            }
            steps{
              // build job with name A
           }

         }


       }

     }

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a fake parameter to the job, and then call it with different value for the parameter for each call. This will force it to call the same job twice.